# Black Duck / Ohloh similar tool

Tags: open-source, code-reuse

I am doing a source that can manage FOSS one of them is by Black Duck Software which is also known for ohloh.net.
I am wondering if anyone knows quite similar tools ?

Comment: Consider also https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit and IMHO this question should be migrated to http://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12):

Below are some of the alternatives:

- [Protecode](http://www.protecode.com/)
- [FOSSology](http://www.fossology.org/projects/fossology)
- [OSS Discovery](http://ossdiscovery.sourceforge.net/) (itself having GNU Affero Public License v3)
- [Palamida](http://www.palamida.com/)
- [Ninka](http://ninka.turingmachine.org/) (itself GNU GPL licensed)

Answer (score 1):

- [Masterbranch](http://masterbranch.com/) but it seems sadly in standby (or dead?) since its main actors were hired by TalentBin around the beginning of 2013.
- [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/) more focused on developers and teams
- [Open Source Software Directory](http://www.opensourcesoftwaredirectory.com/) (only a search tool)
- [The Free Software Directory](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Main_Page) (wiki)

Comment: Not close to what user wants.